# Double Click Radzen Blazor Tree Items

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I am using [Radzen Blazor Tree](https://www.radzen.com/documentation/blazor/tree/) component in a Blazor project. By default the component comes with an event listener for single click on `RadzenTreeItem`. I am hoping to add functionality such that a single click on a `RadzenTreeItem` and a double click on a `RadzenTreeItem` produces different changes to the app. I am thinking of accomplishing this by using a JSInterop for the `dblclick` event listener, but I know this would require having individual html ids for each `RadzenTreeItem` and I am not sure how to go about creating unique ids for a RadzenTreeItem since the tree has a dynamic size. My question is how to create unique ids for a `RadzenTreeItem` if each item is being created in a `RenderFragment` or is there a better way to allow double click functionality?

Below is an example of the C# `RenderFragment` that is used to display the `RadzenTreeItem`:

```
public static RenderFragment<RadzenTreeItem> TreeDesign = (RadzenTreeItem context) => builder =>
{
    builder.OpenComponent<RadzenIcon>(0);
    builder.AddAttribute(1, "Icon", "crop_16_9");
    builder.CloseComponent();
    builder.AddContent(4, context.Text);
};
```

Below is an example of the html code that is calling the `RenderFragment` and creating the tree:

```
<RadzenTree Data="@entries" Change="@OnChange">
    <RadzenTreeLevel Template="@TreeDesign" Text="@GetTextForNode" />
</RadzenTree>
```

Answer (score 0):

5 months old - but I'll give you a shot on how I handle double click years ago in Silverlight.... I created an Observable that would give me an event when there were two clicks within 250MS of each other... this is called a Hot Observable in which the events simply flow by, and when a criteria matches the events, it can raise another event... I can try and dig up the code, as researching for a a double-click event and protection for blazor events.

To add perhaps a bit more clarity - this would listen to the click event you refer to, and if there were two clicks, it would invoke method A, other wise would invoke B for a single click...

A triple click would then become 1 double click, and one single click - but that would depend on the time between the first and thrid event using the Observable...

Comment: Oy, the reference to Silverlight does not add confidence while I am trying to decide if I get into Blazor...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone in the future:

```
    builder =>
    {
            builder.OpenComponent<RadzenIcon>(0);
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "Icon", "crop_16_9");
            builder.CloseComponent();
            builder.OpenElement(2, "div");
            builder.AddAttribute<MouseEventArgs>(3, "ondblclick", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<EventCallback<MouseEventArgs>>(EventCallback.Factory.Create<MouseEventArgs>(this,
     (args) => OnDoubleClick(args, context)
  )));           
            builder.AddContent(10, context.Text);
            builder.CloseElement();
        };
    };

private void OnDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs args, RadzenTreeItem item)
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This is my solution on net7.0:

```js
@code
{
    private RenderFragment<RadzenTreeItem> TreeItemTemplate => context => __builder =>
    {
        <div @ondblclick="@(e => OnDoubleClick(e, context))" style="display: contents">
            <RadzenIcon Icon="crop_16_9" />
            <p>@context.Text</p>
        </div>
    };

    private void OnDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs args, RadzenTreeItem treeItem)
    {
        var item = treeItem.Value;
        // do something with item...
    }
}
```

I use Blazor Server, but it shouldn't matter.